# How to create new columns for unique values on groupby using pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by, transform

Say I have a pandas dataframe like,

```
id,date,school,name
1,2019-01-01,U,Doug
1,2021-01-01,U,Chris
1,2022-01-01,U,Chris
1,2023-01-01,U,Chris
1,2022-01-01,K,Liam
3,2024-01-01,M,Nancy
3,2024-01-01,M,Betty
```

How would I transform it into a format,

```
id,school,name1,name2
1,U,Doug,Chris
1,K,Liam,''
3,M,Nancy,Betty
```

I.e. I want to group by IDs and Schools, and create new columns for each unique Name.

Here is the code to get started.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'id': [1,1,1,1,2,3,3],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01'],
    'school': ['U','U','U','U','K','M','M'],
    'name': ['Doug','Chris','Chris','Chris','Liam','Nancy','Betty']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code to get the unique names by id and school.
Then move each element in each row's list into a separate column and finally rename the columns.

`df_grouped = df.groupby(['id', 'school'])['name'].unique().apply(pd.Series) df_grouped = df_grouped.rename(columns={x: f"name{x+1}" for x in df_grouped.columns}) df_grouped`

Output:

| id | school | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U | Doug | Chris |
| 2 | K | Liam | NaN |
| 3 | M | Nancy | Betty |

Note that our outputs don’t match exactly because there is a slight mismatch in id for school K between your code and the example you provided.

Comment: The renaming doesn't work as expected, but that's fine, the important piece of the puzzle was addressed with the first line.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
cols = ['id', 'school']

g = df.groupby(cols)

out = (pd.concat([pd.concat(
    [x.loc[:, cols].head(1).reset_index(drop=True),
     pd.DataFrame(x['name'].unique()).T], axis=1) for _,x in g])
 .reset_index(drop=True))

out.columns = [x if i <=1 else f'name{i-1}' 
               for i, x in enumerate(out.columns)]
```

Output:

```
   id school  name1  name2
0   1      U   Doug  Chris
1   2      K   Liam    NaN
2   3      M  Nancy  Betty
```